# No message available MVC

Tags: java, spring

I have a message bundle under my resources in src/main the resources with messages are named `messages_en_US.properties` i.e. and I am getting the message to my JSP.

```
@Component
public class Messages {

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    public Messages(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);
    }

    public String get(String code) {
        return accessor.getMessage(code);
    }
}
```

When I used the code above without any beans I had an exception that informed me there is no code for a message. So I added a BeanHelper class as below.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com")
public class BeansHelper {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");

        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

When now I am trying to go on `localhost:8000/` I am getting an 404 that says there is no message available. What is wrong in this code? My messages are under src/main in the resources. But the JSP of course are in WEB-INF/views/ any ideas guys how to solve the problem? I correctly added message properties file to my Local.

Comment: How do you build the webapp IDE or Maven/Gradle?

Comment: Maven I use the spring-boot maybe is there way to declare it in the .properties file instead of creating a class with bean.

Comment: Consider putting your properties files in a locale folder under resources and change   messageSource.setBasename("classpath:locale/messages"); it shouldn't change anything but if you have other file in your path it will be clearer

Comment: Have you add the @EnableMvc somewhere in your spring conf?

Comment: @XavierBouclet unfortunately the result is the same "no message available" what I did I created a "locale" directory in the resources and I putted there all my resource bundles ".properties" files and it does not help me as well.

Comment: I did't add the enableMvc annotation, because it is a spring-boot application. Of course I configured in .properties file the path to the jsp views.

Comment: Ok so may be it's coming from the local resolver. Do you have one in your code?   @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    } Use the us_locale

Comment: @XavierBouclet Even I added this bean it does not help, the result is the same.

Comment: Does it work with a file "messages.properties" without locale? To determine if it's a locale based or properties files

Comment: Try removing classpath in the basename

Comment: @XavierBouclet When I removed the classpath and left "locale/messages" I am getting this message `No message found under code 'welcome.message' for locale 'en_US'.`

Comment: it seems to say there is no message for the key welcome.message in your en_US file